# How to do push down predicate on year,month,day partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

My input file is partitioned like this

table/year/month/day.

I have a requirement to read past 30 days of data. Since the input dataset is huge(spanning over 4 years), how can I implement a push down predicate that filters on just last 30 days of data.

Comment: Are the tables like table/2021/4/5 or a different structure? Can you add a couple examples of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

As it's possible to pass list of target paths, first we can generate the paths before reading files. Here is a sample code assuming that the input data is in parquet format:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_date=datetime.strptime("2021-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
days = 30
paths=[]
for i in range(0, days+1):
    oper_date=start_date - timedelta(days=i)
    path = "table/{year}/{month}/{day}".format(year=oper_date.year, month=oper_date.month, day = oper_date.day)
    paths.append(path)
spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```